# Laptop heating issue - going 50°C even when dealing with documents

Tags: drivers, cpu, overheating, fan, temperature

I have a hp notebook with

> Intel® Core™ i3-5005U CPU @ 2.00GHz × 4
>   Intel® HD Graphics 5500 (Broadwell GT2)
>   4GB RAM

I mainly use it for **reading pdfs** and **typing documents**. But even under normal usage the laptop seems to get quite hot to be placed on my lap. I read through the forum and tried several troubleshooting steps but none of it seems to make any change. I used the `sensors` output here. The `pwmconfig` doesn't seem to work due to driver incompatibility. I can only get the cpu core temp. Below:

```
pch_wildcat_point-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +40.5°C  

acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +27.8°C  

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Physical id 0:  +44.0°C  (high = +105.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
Core 0:         +44.0°C  (high = +105.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
Core 1:         +44.0°C  (high = +105.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
```

Sometimes the temperature goes up as high as **57-60°C** and I couldn't keep it on my lap anymore. I have to set it on a table or move to an air conditioned room. Is there any problem with the drivers or power management settings? Because I just moved from windows to linux and it's been very good except for this heating issue.

Comment: Have you installed any power management packages?  I use 'tlp' which can be installed by `sudo apt-get install tlp` - edit the configurations in `/etc/default/tlp` and `sudo tlp start` or reboot.  I have used an HP laptop in the past, and had very large heat issues that I was unable to resolve.

Comment: This is a normal temperature.

Comment: no i haven't used any. i'll try and install @Charles Green 7

Comment: My current laptop is at 60°C now, just browsing the web. Pretty good compared to an old one that often exceeded 90°C.

Comment: HP probably had proprietary win-only oem software that kept the laptop cooler. While there's nothing wrong (for the laptop) with this temp, you might try a lap desk/cooling tray to put the computer on.

Answer (score 1):

First let me say that 50°C is very good. But it really depends on how high this temp goes under load. If it gets to 70-80°C for long periods of time, I'd be concerned. If it gets to 100°C it's time to turn off the computer before it cooks itself (it may shutdown on its own to protect itself).

Having said that, I'd still do a few things...

- install `intel-microcode` to make sure that your processors have the latest code (this may be already installed)

  `sudo apt-get update`

  `sudo apt-get install intel-microcode`
- check your BIOS version and then go to the HP web site and assure that you've got the latest version. If you don't, then download the latest and install it.
- remove `tlp` if you've installed it, and install `thermald`...

  `sudo apt-get update`

  `sudo apt-get purge tlp`

  `sudo apt-get install thermald`
- here's some info about thermald...

`Thermald` was buggy in early versions of 16.04. Update to 16.04.2 and it should be ok.

`Thermald` comes with a default configuration file at `/etc/thermald/thermal-conf.xml` that will control most computers, but may need to be customized for some computers. See `man thermal-conf.xml` for some details and examples. Once one has modified the configuration file, stop `thermald` and restart it:

```
sudo service thermald restart
```

After installing thermald, I'd stop the `thermald` process, and run it manually as `sudo thermald --no-daemon` to watch its actions in real time. This real time info can be used to create your own customized thermal-conf.xml file. See `man thermald` for more information.

```
sudo service thermald stop
sudo thermald --no-daemon --loglevel=debug
```

You can search for `thermald` here on Ask Ubuntu to see what previous answers there are.

A good starter reference is at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/PowerManagement/ThermalIssues

Comment: i have been using tlp for quite few days now. it's good. why do you recommend thermald? also I can't upgrade my bios and firmware because hp only has drivers and updates downloadable only for windows.

Comment: If tlp is working for you, keep using it. I had tried tlp in the past, and I didn't like it... don't remember why... and I went to thermald, and I liked it, partly because of the configurability of it. Did you install intel-microcode? Please remember to vote/accept my answer if it was helpful. Thanks!

Comment: yes. i've been using tlp and it's very useful now. the temperature doesn't go above 50°C. i have checked the microcode it's up to date. but the bios is not updated. since i'm new to linux i don't know how to do that.

Comment: To update the BIOS, go to the manufacturer's web site, and go to the support section, type in your model #, and see what the latest BIOS version is. Compare that with what version of BIOS you have in your machine, and update it if you're behind. You'll probably have to do the update in Windows.